# Cannot delete file within bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform

```
username@instance-1:~/my_bucket$ 
rm: cannot remove 'file.txt': Permission denied
```

Here's my permissions for the bucket.

[image]

Comment: What's your permission on the bucket? Did you try with the UI? What's the parameters of the bucket? Many inputs are missing

Comment: please see updates. changes permissions an hour ago.

Comment: Do you by any chance have protection turned on for the bucket? Like retention? Not sure if a deletion attempt on a bucket with protection will give that error though. BR

Comment: No idea. Just created the bucket the standard way.

Comment: Did you create the bucket using `gsutil mb` ?

Comment: Permission or retention policy can prevent you to delete object on a bucket!

Comment: Created the bucket using the browser interface. Deleting files works when I use gsutil rm

Comment: I guess. But why does not normal "rm" work?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main factors that can prevent you from deleting objects (files) in a bucket:

1. [Object Permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions#bucket_permissions)
2. [Bucket Retention Policy](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-lock)

As mentioned also by @guillaume blaquiere:

> Permissions or retention policies can prevent you from deleting objects in a bucket.

Regarding your question about `rm` not working is because the normal `rm` command doesn't work with cloud storage services like Google Cloud Storage because `rm` is designed to remove files and directories from the local file system, not from cloud storage.

When you use `rm` in the terminal, it can only delete files and directories stored locally on your machine. It doesn't have the ability to interact with cloud storage services or delete objects from cloud storage buckets.

For cloud storage interactions, you need to use specific commands provided by the cloud storage service. In the case of Google Cloud Storage, the `gsutil rm` command you used worked.

For more information and reference: [rm - Remove objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rm)